# Discontinued browser game

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to know something about a browser game that seems to have been discontinued. I'm not certain that it's been discontinued though. Is it appropriate to ask about the location of the game on this site? I've seen ["Looking for game"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/looking-for-game) but I'm not sure that quite covers this situation.

I want to know a few specific things about the game, that I would be able to see if I was able to find it, but if it should turn out that the game is no longer available, could I ask those questions about the game on this site?

Comment: This sounds like something that would be on topic.  I would word it like "Where can I play the browser game Dominion?"  The post should also include some of the research that you've done so far so we can see the effort you have put in already.

Answer (score 3):

"Identify this game" questions are [off topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-identification) unless you have a specific audiovisual artifact from the game.

You can still ask questions about the game, if you find it, so long as it was publicly released in the past.

Comment: I don't want to identify the game, I know what the game is called, I have played the game over a span of several years, it has a name and people have written about it on the internet in many places. I do not think that the term "Identify this game" applies to it, simply because I have already identified it, I am simply looking for it. The example question on the "Looking for game" question is missing, so I am unable to ascertain whether it adequately addresses the acceptance of questions about discontinued browser games.

Comment: @Alex the deleted question you're referring to was an unambiguous [tag:Identify-This-Game] question. If that's not relevant to what *you* are asking, please clarify.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz The answers I seek about the game though useful to me, would be hard to verify, it would be better if I could find the game and look at it for myself, so I would prefer to ask what happened to the game, if it's moved somewhere else, changed name or changed into something else, can I do that? Does that question fall under the definition of "identify this game" (off-topic) or is it as I thought, under the definition of "looking for game"(on topic)?

Comment: To be specific I want to find out a few things about a game called "Dominion" that I used to play about 12 years ago, I found this post ["Dominion (Browser game)"](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/games/183473-dominion-browser-game-fantasy-war-rpg) dated 2011 which discusses the game in such a way as to indicate that it was still available at that time, but the links to the game on the page lead to domain placeholders and if memory serves me correctly they are the same links that I had used to access the game in the past.

Comment: After some deeper investigation I have found that the game I am looking for has indeed been discontinued. Also, I found a wiki about the game, which hold the answers I'm looking for [The Dominion Encyclopedia](http://dominion.lykanthropos.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)